# 'DevA.Models.Order' is a namespace but is used like a type DevA

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, devexpress

Error 'DevA.Models.Order' is a namespace but is used like a type    ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Order index

```js
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
<h2>Order</h2>
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<DevA.Models.Order>()
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Mvc()
        .Controller("Order")
        .LoadAction("Get")
        .InsertAction("Post")
        .UpdateAction("Put")
        .DeleteAction("Delete")
        .Key("OrderID")
    )
    .RemoteOperations(true)
    .Columns(columns => {

        columns.AddFor(m => m.OrderID);

        columns.AddFor(m => m.OrderDate);

        columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);

        columns.AddFor(m => m.ShipCountry);

        columns.AddFor(m => m.ShipCity);
    })
    .Editing(e => e
        .AllowAdding(true)
        .AllowUpdating(true)
        .AllowDeleting(true)
    )
)
```

Order Model

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DevA.Models {
    public class Order {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        [Required]
   
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(25)]
        public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(25)]
        public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Folder
[image]

Comment: It seems like you have inadvertently used the namespace `DevA.Models.Order` in one of the files. As a result, it conflicts with the type `Order`.

Comment: Exactly, you have a namespace named `DevA.Models.Order`.